# Form onsubmit preventDefault() not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When on submitting the below form it always reloads with parameters in url.Don't know why this is happening:

```
$html .= 
      '<form method="post" id="mailchimp">
           <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" />
           <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name" />
           <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email *" required />
           <button type="submit" id="mailchimp_submit">Subscribe</button>
       </form>';
```

and jquery is below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mailchimp').on('submit', function(e){
        console.log('submitting');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

It neither console logs nor prevent loading.It just keeps loading?Anything i am wrong with any coding?

Comment: Just tested this on my local server all is working fine.

Comment: Have you checked your browsers console for potential JS errors?

Comment: This should work, unless as Magnus says you've got JS errors (maybe caused by other code in the page) preventing anything from running

Comment: P.s. "always reloads with parameters in url" sounds like it's doing a GET request, not even a POST as the form specifies. Are you sure this is definitely the code you're interacting with??

Answer (score 0):

I Think you haven't added the JQuery path.
I test this code and it works fine